# Create a class that inherets DrawableGameComponent in XNA as a CLASS with custom functions

Tags: c#, xna

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;

namespace TileEngine
{
    class Renderer : DrawableGameComponent
    {
        public Renderer(Game game) : base(game)
        {

        }
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch ;

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            base.LoadContent();
        }

        public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }

        public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        public override void Initialize()
        {
            base.Initialize();
        }

        public RenderTarget2D new_texture(int width, int height)
        {
            Texture2D TEX = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, width, height);   //create the texture to render to
            RenderTarget2D Mine = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, width, height);
            GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(Mine); //set the render device to the reference provided
            //maybe base.draw can be used with spritebatch. Idk. We'll see if the order of operation
            //works out. Wish I could call base.draw here.
            return Mine;    //I'm hoping that this returns the same instance and not a copy.
        }

        public void draw_texture(int width, int height, RenderTarget2D Mine)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null); //Set the renderer to render to the backbuffer again
            Rectangle drawrect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height); //Set the rendering size to what we want
            spriteBatch.Begin();                        //This uses spritebatch to draw the texture directly to the screen  
            spriteBatch.Draw(Mine, drawrect, Color.White); //This uses the color white
            spriteBatch.End();      //ends the spritebatch
            //Call base.draw after this since it doesn't seem to recognize inside the function
            //maybe base.draw can be used with spritebatch. Idk. We'll see if the order of operation
            //works out. Wish I could call base.draw here.
        }
    }
}
```

I solved a previous issue where I wasn't allowed to access GraphicsDevice outside the main Default 'main' class
Ie "Game" or "Game1" etc.
Now I have a new issue. FYi no one told me that it would be possible to use GraphicsDevice References to cause it to not be null by using the drawable class. (hopefully after this last bug is solved it doesn't still return null)

Anyways at present the problem is that I can't seem to get it to initialize as an instance in my main program.
Ie

```
Renderer tileClipping;
```

and I'm unable to use it such as
it is to be noted i haven't even gotten to testing these two steps below but before it compiled
but when those functions of this class were called it complained that it can't render to a null device.
Which meant that the device wasn't being initialized. I had no idea why. It took me hours to google this.
I finally figured out the words I needed.. which were "do my rendering in XNA in a seperate class"
now I haven't used the addcomponent function because I don't want it to only run these functions automatically
and I want to be able to call the custom ones.

In a nutshell what I want is:
*access to rendering targets and graphics device OUTSIDE default class
*passing of Rendertarget2D (which contain textures and textures should automatically be passed with a rendering target? )
*the device should be passed to this function as well OR the device should be passed to this function as a byproduct of passing the rendertarget (which is automatically associated with the render device it was given originally)
*I'm assuming I'm dealing with abstracted pointers here so when I pass a class object or instance, I should be recieving the SAME object , I referenced, and not a copy that has only the lifespan of the function running.

*the purpose for all these options: I want to initialize new 2d textures on the fly to customize tileclipping and even the X , y Offsets of where a WHOLE texture will be rendered, and the X and Y offsets of where tiles
will be rendered ON that surface. 
This is why. And I'll be doing region based lighting effects per tile or even per 8X8 pixel spaces.. we'll see
I'll also be doing sprite rotations on the whole texture then copying it again to a circular masked
texture, and then doing a second copy for only solid tiles for masked rotated collisions on sprites.
I'll be checking the masked pixels for my collision, and using raycasting possibly to check for collisions on 
those areas.

The sprite will stay in the center, when this rotation happens.
Here is a detailed diagram:

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/INf9K.gif

I'll be using texture2D for steps 4-6
I suppose for steps 1 as well.
Now ontop of that, the clipping size (IE the sqaure rendered)
will be able to be shrunk or increased, on a per frame basis
Therefore I can't use the same static size for my main texture2d and I can't use just the backbuffer
Or we get the annoying flicker.
Also I will have multiple instances of the renderer class so that I can freely pass textures around
as if they are playing cards (in a sense) layering them ontop of eachother, cropping them how i want
and such.
and then using spritebatch to simply draw them at the locations I want.
Hopefully this makes sense, and yes I will be planning on using alpha blending but only after
all tiles have been drawn.. 
The masked collision is important and Yes I am avoiding using math on the tile rendering and instead resorting to image manipulation in video memory which is WHY I need this to work the way I'm intending it to work and not in the default way that XNA seems to handle graphics.

Thanks to anyone willing to help.

I hate the code form offered, because then I have to rely on static presence of an update function.
What if I want to kill that update function or that object, but have it in memory, but just have it temporarily inactive? I'm making the assumption here the update function of one of these gamecomponents is automatic ?
Anyways this is as detailed as I can make this post hopefully someone can help me solve the issue. Instead of tell me "derrr don't do it this wayyy" which is what a few people told me (but they don't understand the actual goal I have in mind)

I'm trying to create basically a library where I can copy images freely no matter the size, i just have to specify the size in the function then as long as a reference to that object exists it should be kept alive? right? :/ anyways..

Anything else? I Don't know. I understand object oriented coding but I don't understand this XNA
It's beggining to feel impossible to do anything custom in it without putting ALL my rendering code into the draw function of the main class

```
tileClipping.new_texture(GraphicsDevice, width, height) 
tileClipping.Draw_texture(...)
```